# PHP Storm 2017.1 SFTP connection error

Tags: sftp, phpstorm-2017.1

I am on MAC OS using PHP STORM 2017.1 upon trying to connect in any form using SFTP I get the error 385. I have tried connecting using FileZilla and successful. Any help would be amazing.

Regards.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [apple.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. Check what do you have in ~/Library/Logs/PyCharm2017.1/idea.log. My issue was in malformed ~/.ssh/known_hosts file